# sp_execute chooses different query plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

So this is the scenario:

Table has many fields. 
Field2 is the only field in clustered index.
There exists Field1, Field2 unique index which does not include any other fields.

Table has 500000 rows, of which 499900 have empty value for Field1.

Query 1:

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM Table WITH(UPDLOCK) 
WHERE (Field1='XXX') ORDER BY Field1 DESC, Field2 DESC OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Produces Index Seek to unique index Field1,Field2, then key lookup to clustered index, and is very fast.

However,

```
Declare @P1 int;  
Exec sp_prepare @P1 output,   
N'@0 nvarchar(20)',  
N'SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM Table WITH(UPDLOCK) 
WHERE (Field1=@0) ORDER BY Field1 DESC, Field2 DESC OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)';  
Exec sp_execute @P1, N'XXX'
EXEC sp_unprepare @P1;
```

Produces a clustered index scan, which is slow.

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE does not help, so it's not the problem with cashed query plan.

Question is, why the difference?

Thank you.

edited: accidently put the same thing into second query, updated to reflect it correctly.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if the @P1 parameter was hardcoded into the command string. What is the execution time then?

Comment: Hardcoding the parameter makes the plans same.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the parameter which is in varaiable, IF you hardcode that it will return to same plan, or if you put parameters in the normal execution it will generate the plan to scan.

Comment: well obviously that is the only difference, but why? where is this documented?

Comment: You can get some info in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(SQL.100).aspx) article. In my opinion it is well explained in a book by Itzik Ben-Gan 'Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012' chapter 17, lesson 2: 'using parametrized queries and batch operations'.

Comment: Which part of the article do you think has a relation to this?